# Does Xgboost use feature subsetting?

Tags: boosting

Random forests select a subset of the features at each node and only considers those features as candidate splits.  Wikipedia says this is sometimes called [feature bagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#From_bagging_to_random_forests).

Does XGBoost also use this technique, in its tree learning, when growing an individual tree?  Or does it consider all possible features when examining possible splits?

I read the original paper on XGBoost [1], and couldn't tell from what was in that paper.  Section 2.3 of that paper mentions "column sub-sampling" , which appears to be the same thing, and it mentions columns sub-sampling is used in random forests, but doesn't explicitly indicate whether it is used in XGBoost.

References:
[1] [XGBoost: A Scalable Tree Boosting System](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754).  Tianqi Chen, Carlos Guestrin.  KDD'16, arXiv:1603.02754.

Comment: For what it's worth, I got a big boost in model performance on my problem when I used XGBoost with extreme feature subsampling (very few features per tree), see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279630/xgboost-feature-subsampling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See documentaiton [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), and search `colsample_bytree`.

> colsample_bytree [default=1]
>
> subsample ratio of columns when constructing each tree.
>
> range: (0,1]

By default, it uses all features. But you can set `colsample_bytree` parameter to get a subset on features.